# Tried to publish before configured topic id 125

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am using rosserial arduino, from the tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) I made my custom message file which contains string and integer data types in catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg/Datatype.msg  and converted it into a header file  Datatype.h, After that I ran following command`rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .` It created header datatype.h in /sketchbook/libraries/roslib/beginner_tutorials. Now I am able to compile my header file . But while running serial_node.py I am getting following errors:

```
pankaj@pankaj-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:~$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0`[INFO] [WallTime: 1461149079.336082] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1461149079.343509] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1461149082.330481] Creation of publisher failed: beginner_tutorials
`ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1461149083.266678] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1461149083.266678] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1461149083.266678] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
```

Other examples of arduino like Hello world  are working fine. I am getting error only when I use my custom message header.`Why am I getting this error ? please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232355/tried-to-publish-before-configured-topic-id-125/) by [pankaj patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26256/pankaj-patel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can serial_node.py access the msg definition?
Looks like you haven't run message generation through catkin for your custom message package.
Or you haven't added devel/install space into your path.

Tutorial here:  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg

---

Originally posted by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) with karma: 124 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pankaj patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26256/pankaj-patel/) on 2016-04-20**:
Hey Vmato thanks a lot. I was forgetting to add install path. It worked now.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-10-21**:
Hi patel, may I know your detail steps to solve this problem?

**Comment by [mertwlf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52852/mertwlf/) on 2020-03-25**:
hello, can you share how exactly you solved it please. I am having the same problem and ı am unable to solve it?

**Comment by [ramizdayi18.04](https://answers.ros.org/users/139553/ramizdayi18.04/) on 2023-05-30**:
hi guys, can you give us a more detail info

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar topic when publishing anything but `std_msgs` from rosserial_arduino. Specifically, I am publishing `sensor_msgs/JointState` messages.
For me adding `nh.negotiateTopics` after all `nh.advertise` and `nh.subscribe` calls did the trick:

```
# subscribe and advertise topics
nh.subscribe(position_sub);
nh.advertise(joint_pub);
# give serial_node.py a chance to get to know the topics
nh.negotiateTopics();
```

---

Originally posted by [Tuebel](https://answers.ros.org/users/59273/tuebel/) with karma: 31 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3